# Can't do POST requests with Polymer's core-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, web-component, core-elements

This is what I have:

```js
Polymer('my-element', {
  created: function() {
    this.data = {
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'john@doe.com'
    };  
  },
  
  handleResponse: function(e, d) {
    console.log(d.response);
  }
});
```

```html
<core-ajax
           id="ajax"
           auto
           url="/test"
           method="POST"
           handleAs="json"
           body="{{data}}"
           on-core-response="{{handleResponse"}}>
</core-ajax>
```

And I have a server set up to return the body of the POST message when the user posts to /test.

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.body);
}
```

However, this is what I get as response on the console:

Object {object Object: ""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

core ajax all data you want to get with post must be sent with params attribute not body attribute.

that would make your core ajax tag look like

```
<core-ajax
       id="ajax"
       auto
       url="/test"
       method="POST"
       handleAs="json"
       params="{{data}}"
       on-core-response="{{handleResponse"}}>
</core-ajax>
```

that would allow you to catch the data like normal in node

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body);
}
```

it is confusing cause in node you think of params as get data and body as post data but this doesn't matter with core ajax. all data get or post is sent with the params attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, then, what do I use the body attribute for?

Comment: the docs say body = "Optional raw body content to send when method === "POST"." so  idk actually i have been a little confused by it myself. the data can be used when sent in body attribute. i am not sure how in node but with php you can use  $post = file_get_contents("php://input"); and get the data but you have to json_decode or parse in another manner to actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like core-ajax performs the AJAX call before this.data in ready.

Try 'manuel' AJAX request initiation, i.e. ajax.go()
Do this inside:

```
 created: function() {
    this.data = {
       name: 'John Doe',
       email: 'john@doe.com'
     }; 
    var respuesta = this.$.ajax;
    console.log(respuesta);
    respuesta.go();
},
```

Example [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhduEb5OkoTtH8QjcQBx?p=info)